# How to get output from stored procedure in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC and I've made a stored procedure. I want to call the stored procedure and then output the data output using the `System.out.println` in Java. How do I do that?

Below was my original stored procedure. I would like to get this to work but from reading I don't know if it is possible

```
DELIMITER $$
            CREATE
            PROCEDURE CountMembers()
            BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(MEMBER_ID) FROM Members;
            END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Here is what I have changed it to because it seems to get the output this is what might have to be done.

```
DELIMITER $$
        CREATE
        PROCEDURE CountMembers(OUT m_count VARCHAR(30))
        BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(MEMBER_ID) INTO m_count FROM Members;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I know to run it I will have to make a callable Statement and then I've seen where `String userCount = callableStatement.getString(1);` can get the output. Basically I've read a lot of information, but I'm having a hard time putting it all together.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tag the particular database platform you are using. It looks like it might be [tag:mysql], but it is always best to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Just added it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, be aware that COUNT(MEMBER_ID) will return an integer value but your are selecting it into a VARCHAR variable.

Next, I think you are looking for something like:

```
    CallableStatement stm = connection.prepareCall("{ call CountMembers(?) }");
    stm.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    stm.execute();
    String m_count = stm.getString(1);
    stm.close();
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I did however have to add `final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/test?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"` to my code because I got an error saying  "does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types." Just in case any user ends up having my same issues.